# write.csv2 error in decimal format export

Tags: rstudio

I'm a newbie using R so maybe I'll do stupid questions and I apologize for them.

I'm exporting a dataset from Rstudio using write.csv2 and sometimes in the same dataset numbers are converted with "," as decimal separator and sometimes they are converted with "." as decimal separator.

I don't understand why.

here you are finding the code I'm using:

```
write.csv2(LT_articolo_perimetro, file= exp_LT_1, row.names = F )
```

and below the structure of the dataset

```
$ CODFOR              <fct> 
$ CLASSE_MERCEOLOGICA <fct> 
$ CODICE_ARTICOLO     <fct> 
$ media_LT_reale      <time> 
$ sdev_LT_reale       <dbl> 
$ LT_reale_q80        <time>
$ LT_reale_q85        <time>
$ LT_reale_q90        <time>
$ LT_reale_q95        <time>
$ LT_reale_max        <time>
$ nrow                <int>
```

the output is

[image: Image of the error]

Anyone knows how to fix it?

thank you very much

Comment: If you are new to the forum [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm a newbie...

the problem is that the type of the following variables is time

LT_reale_q80
LT_reale_q85
LT_reale_q90
LT_reale_q95
LT_reale_max

after converting them in numeric, the problem disappear